# Why does -[NSString compare:options:] return true when the strings are not equal?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am checking if a string appears twice in a row within an array. This code doesn't seem to work, as it just prints out the entire array. What am I missing?

```
NSString *nameString =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words"
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                 error:NULL];

NSArray *names = [nameString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

//Save last item
NSMutableString *lastOne = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:20];

// Go through the array one string at a time
for (NSString *n in names) {

    if ([n compare:lastOne options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", n);
    }

    [lastOne setString:n];


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`compare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:) and related functions don't return booleans, they return an [`NSComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparisonResult). If you want to see if a string is equal you should instead use

```
if ([n compare:lastOne options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
```

Comment: Great answer, you beat me to it

Comment: `isEqual:`/`isEqualToString:`, of course, are options that _do_ return `BOOL`, but don't provide the case insensitivity option.

Comment: @cobbal it still doesn't work
  `for (NSString *n in names) {
            
            //make it lowercase
            
            if ([lastOne caseInsensitiveCompare:n] == NSOrderedSame) {
                NSLog(@"%@", n);
            }
            
            [lastOne setString:n];
            
            }
    
        }`